# python object constructor not being called?

Tags: python

I am using python 2.7.3
I have a couple of classes:

class GpioSettings:

```
class GpioSettings(object):
  __initialized__ = False
  PIR_PIN = 6
  GPIO = None
  RISING = None
  FALLING = None
  IN = None

  def __init__(self):
    print "starting to initialize gpio settings"
    if GpioSettings.__initialized__:
      print "gpio settings already initialized now"
      return
    else:
      print "initializing gpio settings now"
      GpioSettings.__initialized__ = True
      try:
        import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
        GpioSettings.GPIO = GPIO
        GpioSettings.RISING = GPIO.RISING
        GpioSettings.FALLING = GPIO.FALLING
        GpioSettings.IN = GPIO.IN
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GpioSettings.__piFunctionsLoaded__ = True
      except:
        GpioSettings.__piFunctionsLoaded__ = False

  @staticmethod
  def piFunctionsLoaded():
    return GpioSettings.__piFunctionsLoaded__

  @staticmethod
  def gpio():
    return GpioSettings.GPIO
```

class Pir:

```
import os
import sys
import time
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("/home/pi/garageMonitor/django/lib"))
from gpioSettings import GpioSettings
from osUtils import checkUser

class Pir(object):
  def __init__(self, callback):
    self.gpio = GpioSettings()
    if not self.gpio.piFunctionsLoaded():
      return
    self.gpio.gpio().setup(self.gpio.PIR_PIN, gpio.IN)
    self.gpio.gpio().add_event_detect(self.gpio.PIR_PIN, gpio.RISING, callback=callback, bouncetime=300)

def testCallback(channel):
  print "Motion Detected on " + str(channel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  checkUser()
  gpio = GpioSettings()
  if gpio.piFunctionsLoaded():
    print "loaded"
    pir = Pir(testCallback)
    time.sleep(30)
  else:
    print "not loaded"
```

and python file startPio.py:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("/home/pi/garageMonitor/django/lib"))
from gpioSettings import GpioSettings
from osUtils import checkUser
from piPir import Pir

def pirCallback(channel):
  print "Motion Detected on " + str(channel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  checkUser()
  print "initializing gpio now"
  gpio = GpioSettings()
  if gpio.piFunctionsLoaded():
    print "loaded here"
    pir = Pir(pirCallback)
  else:
    print "not loaded"
```

I am trying to make a singleton of the GpioSettings class so that I can use it in multiple classes.  It may not be running on the appropriate hardware (and RPi.GPIO may not be available) so I am trying to shield this from the other classes.

If I run:
sudo python ./piPir.py it works fine (GpioSettings is called) and I get the expected output:

```
starting to initialize gpio settings
initializing gpio settings now
gpio settings already initialized now
loaded
starging to initialize gpio settings
gpio settings already initialized now
Motion Detected on 6
```

If I run:
sudo python ./startPio.py (both GpioSettings and piPir are called) I get the following:

```
sudo python ./startPio.py            
initializing gpio now
loaded here
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./startPio.py", line 17, in <module>
    pir = Pir(pirCallback)
  File "/home/pi/garageMonitor/django/lib/piPir.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.gpio.gpio().setup(self.gpio.PIR_PIN, gpio.IN)
AttributeError: GpioSettings instance has no attribute 'gpio'
```

What's killing me is that "starting to initialize gpio settings" does not get printed when **"gpio = GpioSettings()"** is called from startPio.py!

Obviously I am tired and need some rest as I am sure it is obvious.

So I put everything into one file to make debugging a little easier:

```
class GpioSettings(object):
  __initialized__ = False
  PIR_PIN = 6
  GPIO = None
  RISING = None
  FALLING = None
  IN = None

  def __init__(self):
    print "starting to initialize gpio settings"
    if GpioSettings.__initialized__:
      print "gpio settings already initialized now"
      return
    else:
      print "initializing gpio settings now"
      GpioSettings.__initialized__ = True
      try:
        import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
        GpioSettings.GPIO = GPIO
        GpioSettings.RISING = GPIO.RISING
        GpioSettings.FALLING = GPIO.FALLING
        GpioSettings.IN = GPIO.IN
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GpioSettings.__piFunctionsLoaded__ = True
      except:
        GpioSettings.__piFunctionsLoaded__ = False

  @staticmethod
  def piFunctionsLoaded():
    return GpioSettings.__piFunctionsLoaded__

  @staticmethod
  def gpio():
    return GpioSettings.GPIO


##############################################################################
##############################################################################
##############################################################################

class Pir(object):
  def __init__(self, callback):
    print "intializing PIR"
    self.gpio = GpioSettings()
    if not self.gpio.piFunctionsLoaded():
      return
    self.gpio.gpio().setup(self.gpio.PIR_PIN, gpio.IN)
    self.gpio.gpio().add_event_detect(self.gpio.PIR_PIN, gpio.RISING, callback=callback, bouncetime=300)

##############################################################################
##############################################################################
##############################################################################


import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("/home/pi/garageMonitor/django/lib"))
#from gpioSettings import GpioSettings
from osUtils import checkUser
#from piPir import Pir

def pirCallback(channel):
  print "Motion Detected on " + str(channel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  checkUser()
  print "initializing gpio now"
  gpio = GpioSettings()
  if gpio.piFunctionsLoaded():
    print "loaded here"
    pir = Pir(pirCallback)
  else:
    print "not loaded"
```

And it works fine!!??!!!

```
sudo python startPio.py
initializing gpio now
starting to initialize gpio settings
initializing gpio settings now
loaded here
intializing PIR
starting to initialize gpio settings
gpio settings already initialized now
```

Comment: Not sure if related with your issue, but one potential big problem in the code above is that if you are runningthis under Python 2.x, your classes should inherit from `object`. Making then not inheriting from object will break your code in strange ways.

Comment: Although this was a great catch (implemented suggestion above), it did not fix my problem.  I am still getting the exact same problem

Comment: Where's your implementation of `checkUser`? Have you confirmed that the correct modules are indeed loaded (especially that `GpioSettings` is indeed from the source you've posted)?

Comment: I renamed GpioSettings to MyGpioSettings and am having the same problem.  I commented out all references to checkUser and I am still having the same problem.  I am really surprised that it all works in the same file but not across the three files.

Comment: A conditional import in an `__init__`? A huge confusion between Class and instance members, and cross-module naming confusions. My recommendation: 1) remove all class level data members, 2) remove all `@staticmethod` decorations 3) remove all private member `__declarations` 4) double-double `__underscores__` [are reserved by the language](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers) 5) try to get the spaghetti out. These will yield at least an answerable question and probably teach you something about how to Python properly.

Comment: i would start by verifying (using `id`) that the `gpio` in `startPio` and `piPir` are actually the same class, and that it actually has that instance. if you want through it, you'll probably see that some of your assumptions aren't true.. it looks ok, but yeah, this is weird python. Also, a module is effectively a singleton in python - unless you _really_ need a class for some reason, in which case look up the Singleton decorator - so these would be better done as simple modules.

Answer (score 1):

**I gave up. Thanks to Corley Brigman, here is what I wound up with:**

piPir.py:

```
    import os
    import sys
    sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("/home/pi/garageMonitor/django/lib"))
    import gpioSettings
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

class Pir(object):
  def __init__(self, callback):
    GPIO.setup(gpioSettings.PIR_PIN, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(gpioSettings.PIR_PIN, GPIO.RISING, callback=callback, bouncetime=300)
```

gpioSettings.py:

```
PIR_PIN = 6
DOOR_UP_PIN = 21
DOOR_DOWN_PIN = 22
```

gpioStart.py:

```
import os
import sys
import time
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("/home/pi/garageMonitor/django/lib"))
from osUtils import checkUser
from piPir import Pir
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

def pirCallback(channel):
  print "Motion Detected on " + str(channel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  checkUser()
  pir = Pir(pirCallback)
  time.sleep(30000)
```

Comment: The final solution is in my answer